# Giving a timestamp with a metric to Prometheus

Tags: timestamp, prometheus

I'm trying to give Prometheus a data with a timestamp like follows:

```
"# HELP ABAP_MESSAGE_SERVER_HTTP_AVAIL2 Active Users\\n" +
"# TYPE ABAP_MESSAGE_SERVER_HTTP_AVAIL2 gauge\\n" +
"ABAP_MESSAGE_SERVER_HTTP_AVAIL2{Provider="DP_SYSMON",} 100.01 1670401800\\n"
```

When trying to do this, I get this error from Prometheus:

```
msg="Error on ingesting samples that are too old or are too far into the future" num_dropped=1
```

I am using the java library normally maybe a function in there can help with the timestamps? The example given is using a writer as I don't know how to add a timestamp with the library.

I have tried using different times for the timestamp if it may be now or an hour in the past, an hour in the future or even timestamps that are associated to other data points in `Prometheus`. None of these seem to solve the problem.

I was wondering if my syntax is wrong or where could this error come from? Is there another way to give timestamps to Prometheus or is this not really supported? Any info would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Metric timestamps are in milliseconds, but you're using seconds.

Add 3 zeros to your number and it should work.

`The timestamp is an int64 (milliseconds since epoch, i.e. 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, excluding leap seconds), represented as required by Go's ParseInt() function.`

https://github.com/prometheus/docs/blob/main/content/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats.md